# What is wrong when you get an "Unrecognized configuration section runtime" configuration exception

Tags: .net, exception, configuration

In particular from this web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="RStrace" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RSTraceSectionHandler,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics" />
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultTraceSwitch" value="3" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <RStrace>
    <add name="FileName" value="ReportServerService_" />
    <add name="FileSizeLimitMb" value="32" />
    <add name="KeepFilesForDays" value="14" />
    <add name="Prefix" value="appdomain, tid, time" />
    <add name="TraceListeners" value="file" />
    <add name="TraceFileMode" value="unique" />
    <add name="Components" value="all:3" />
  </RStrace>
  <runtime>
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces"
              publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"
              culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.242.0"
             newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.242.0"
             newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to 'escape' the XML (use the PRE block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like .NET was installed using a corporate re-packaging technology and not all the bits were there. We installed from the original Microsoft image and all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have found that the `machine.config` file was missing. It should be located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config` on my machine. There existed a `machine.config.defaults` in the same directory. I made a copy of the file in the same directory and renamed it to `machine.config`. Applications loaded normally afterwards for me.

I discovered the absence of the `machine.config` file through use of the [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/). After running it for .NET framework 4.7.1, a log file in `%temp%` shows up whose name starts with `setupverifier_errors`. It contains a list of files that are missing and `machine.config` was on top of the list. If restoring `machine.config` did not fix it for you, it might be worth it to check other files listed in the log file.

Comment: This tool has detected the errors for me, but more files were missing. A Windows 10 upgrade (2004 -> 20H2) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when you are missing an entry in the configSections area.  In the above example, you probably need to add a line similar to this:

```
<section name="runtime" type="your-datatype"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that it's finding the <runtime> tag in you file, but doesn't know what to do with it.  It may be in the wrong section.

As <runtime> is a standard web.config element, something screwy is going on.  Try removing the RTrace section.  If that works, restore the Rtrace section after the runtime section.

Comment: I think it may be because the customer in question has "repackaged" .NET in order to push it out to corporate systems.